# Create main vars with nested vars

Tags: terraform, hcl

I'm configuring a terraform module with lambda and VPC endpoint deployment, and currently, I would like to use more cleaner way of defining and accessing the vars in the code

S3 vars are used for creating lambda function aws resource and vpc endpoint vars for creating aws_vpc_endpoint resource

Below are my local vars which have the same conditions

Is it possible to somehow create one var for s3 and a second one for vpc endpoint where I can apply only one condition to the entire var without duplicating?

```
 s3_bucket         = var.s3_existing_package != null ? try(var.s3_existing_package.bucket, null) : null
 s3_key            = var.s3_existing_package != null ? try(var.s3_existing_package.key, null) : null
 s3_object_version = var.s3_existing_package != null ? try(data.aws_s3_object.this.version_id, null) : null

 ## VPC endpoint
 vpc_id                                     = var.enable_api_gw && var.api_gw_endpoint_type == "PRIVATE" ? try(var.vpc_id, null) : null
 vpc_endpoint_subnet_ids                    = var.enable_api_gw && var.api_gw_endpoint_type == "PRIVATE" ? try(var.vpc_endpoint_subnet_ids, null) : null
 vpc_endpoint_default_sg_allowed_cidrs      = var.enable_api_gw && var.api_gw_endpoint_type == "PRIVATE" ? try(var.vpc_endpoint_default_sg_allowed_cidrs, null) : null
 vpc_endpoint_additional_security_group_ids = var.enable_api_gw && var.api_gw_endpoint_type == "PRIVATE" ? try(var.vpc_endpoint_additional_security_group_ids, []) : []
```

Comment: Just to understand the problem better, is it something like you want to create the s3 and lambda + vpc endpoint only if some variable says create it else do nothing ??
If this is the case you can use count for conditional resources. 

Or is it you want to pass different vpc / subnets and other variables depending on the conditions? If yes i suspect this if is for multiple deployments in same account or different accounts also. You can pass in the correct values as inputs in the module that you will create. Also can leverage someting called as Terragrunt to orchestrate the tf.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals#declaring-a-local-value

> The expressions in local values are not limited to literal constants; they can also reference other values in the module in order to transform or combine them, including variables, resource attributes, or other local values:

Here is one example using your code

```
variable "existing" {
  default = true
}

locals {
  s3 = var.existing != null ? {
    bucket         = "foo"
    key            = "x"
    object_version = "123"
  } : null
}

output "s3" {
  value = local.s3
}
```

and a terraform plan on that will show

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + s3 = {
      + bucket         = "foo"
      + key            = "x"
      + object_version = "123"
    }
```

---

My recommendation, start simple like that one variable one local and output, complicate that local as much as you want to test then bring it to your project and integrate with the rest of your resources, the same `try` as you have should be no problem

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can define local blocks for your s3 and vpc endpoints.

```
locals {
   s3_vars = var.existing != null ? {
   bucket         =  try(var.s3_existing_package.bucket, null)
   key            =  try(var.s3_existing_package.key, null)
   object_version =  try(var.s3_existing_package.key, null)
  } : {
   bucket         = null
   key            = null
   object_version = null
   }
}
```

And your resource block would be like :

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "example" {
  s3_bucket         = local.s3_vars.bucket
  s3_key            = local.s3_vars.key
  s3_object_version = local.s3_vars.object_version
}
```